# How to create 2 records with different IDs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a project where people need to trade credits between them.

I'm doing this

User model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :create_bank_account

  has_one :bank_account, inverse_of: :user, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :account_transactions, inverse_of: :user, through: :bank_account
end
```

Bank model

```
class BankAccount < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :bank_account

  validates :balance, presence: true, numericality: true
  validates :user, presence: true

  has_many :account_transactions, inverse_of: :bank_account, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :account_transactions

  before_validation :load_defaults

  def load_defaults
    if self.new_record?
    self.balance = 4.0
  end
end
```

Account transactions model

```
class AccountTransaction < ApplicationRecord
  after_initialize :set_default_status, if: :new_record?
  after_commit :transfer, on: :create

  belongs_to :bank_account, inverse_of: :account_transactions

  enum transaction_type: [ :Received, :Sent ]
  enum status: [ :Approved, :Canceled ]

  def set_default_status
    self.status ||= :"Approved"
  end

  private

  def transfer
    source_account = BankAccount.find(source)
    target_account = BankAccount.find(target)
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      source_account.balance -= amount
      target_account.balance += amount
      source_account.save!
      target_account.save!
    end
  end   
end
```

The credit transfer is working fine.

But I need to create the records with the bank_id of each user.

How would i create those 2 account transactions records?

A record with bank_id of user A and another record with bank_id of user B.

I do not know if the best way to handle transactions between users would be this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you need 2 records for `AccountTransaction`?
I strongly recommend you to save 2 `bank_account` ids in the `AccountTransaction` model, see:

```rb
# acount_transaction.rb
class AccountTransaction < ApplicationRecord
  after_initialize :set_default_status, if: :new_record?
  after_commit :transfer, on: :create

  belongs_to :target_bank_account, foreign_key: 'target_id', class_name: 'BankAccount'
  belongs_to :source_bank_account, foreign_key: 'source_id', class_name: 'BankAccount'

  enum transaction_type: [ :Received, :Sent ]
  enum status: [ :Approved, :Canceled ]

  def set_default_status
    self.status ||= :"Approved"
  end

  private

  def transfer
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      self.source_bank_account.balance -= amount
      self.target_bank_account.balance += amount
      source_bank_account.save!
      target_bank_account.save!
    end
  end   
end
```

You just need to create a new migration adding the `target_id` and `source_id` to `AcountTransaction`.

If you do it, you will be able to save in just 1 record the `source_account` and the `target_account`, this makes more sense, what do you think?

## Update

You should remove the `bank_id` and create 2 new `foreing_keys`: `target_bank_id` and `source_bank_id` for `AccountModel`.

In the `BankAccount` model, you can add the following lines:

```rb
# bank_account.rb
has_many incoming_transfers, foreign_key: 'target_bank_id', class_name: 'AccountTransaction' 
has_many made_transfers
, foreign_key: 'source_bank_id', class_name: 'AccountTransaction'
```

After it, you can check for each `BankAccount` how many transfers are made and received!

You can see more about this kind of association [clicking here!](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins)

Comment: It makes sense, but I did not completely understand. My idea would be to have 2 records, to show the transfers made by each one.
In that case, do I have to remove the bank_id from the account transaction? And how would I show the transfers from each of them?

Comment: I've Updated the answer. You should remove the `bank_id` and replace it with 2 foreing keys: `source_bank_id` and `target_bank_id`